# My RPi (4B 4Gb) cannot do 'multiTasking'

Tags: matplotlib

I have a nema23 stepper motor driven by the DM542T drive and hooked up to my RPi(PUL=Pin18 DIR=Pin23); I also have an industrial Laser Distance sensor(Wenglor CP35MHT80   https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2335720/Wenglor-Cp08mht80.html#product-CP35MHT80) which gives me back analog readings 4-20mA; this sensor is then connected to a module that converts 4-20mA to 0V-5V so I can hook it up to my ADS1115 converter; from this ADC then straight to RPi.  Basically the laser is attached to a linear actuator(driven by the nema23) and it is basically ''scannining'' the surface of a tyre: the goal is to reproduce the profile of that tyre surface using the distances read by the sensor(through the ADS1115) and then plot them into a graph as a continous line.   Here is the catch: I've managed to put up some basic code to the 2 tasks independently, meaning that I can read correctly the values from the sensor and I also can drive the stepper motor as I wish(INDEPENDENTLY MEANING EACH TASK SEPARETLY). My goal is to have the values read from the sensor to be plotted WHILE the stepper motor is moving and when I run the code it simply DOES NOT GIVE ANY SIGN OF LIVE even though I've used successfully the same EXACT CODEs separetly.  Here are my codes:     this is to read the values from the sensor:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create an ADS1115 ADC instance
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

# Set the gain (the range of the analog input voltage)
GAIN = 2/3

# Set the mapping equation to convert analog values to mm
analog_values = [7200, 13600]
mm_range = [50, 300]
mapping_equation = np.interp(analog_values, [min(analog_values), max(analog_values)], mm_range)

# Initialize plot
plt.ion()  # Turn on interactive mode
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Mapped Value (mm)')

# Set y-axis limits
plt.ylim([mm_range[1], mm_range[0]])

# Read the analog value from channel A3 continuously and convert to mm
x_data = []
y_data = []
while True:
    analog_value = adc.read_adc(3, gain=GAIN)
    mm_value = np.interp(analog_value, analog_values, mapping_equation)
    mm_value = int(mm_value)  # Convert to integer to remove decimal part
    print("Analog value from channel A1: {}, mapped to mm: {}".format(analog_value, mm_value))
    x_data.append(time.time())
    y_data.append(mm_value)
    ax.plot(x_data, y_data)
    plt.pause(0.1)  # Pause for 0.1 seconds to update plot
```

This is whatI use for driving the stepper::

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3 

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pul=18
dir=23
 
GPIO.setup(pul, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(dir, GPIO.OUT)

delay= 0.0001
steps=27000*10

GPIO.output(dir, GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(delay)

for i in range(steps):
        GPIO.output(pul, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(delay)
        GPIO.output(pul, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(delay)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

and when I try to basically combine the codes I came up with this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import concurrent.futures

# Set the GPIO mode to BCM
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Define the PUL and DIR pins
PUL_PIN = 18
DIR_PIN = 23

# Set the PUL and DIR pins as output
GPIO.setup(PUL_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(DIR_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

# Define the step delay
DELAY = 0.0001

# Define the number of steps
STEPS = 127000

# Set the direction to clockwise
GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)

# Create an ADS1115 ADC instance
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

# Set the gain (the range of the analog input voltage)
GAIN = 2/3

# Set the mapping equation to convert analog values to mm
analog_values = [4800, 13600]
mm_range = [50, 300]
mapping_equation = np.interp(analog_values, [min(analog_values), max(analog_values)], mm_range)

# Create a list to store the mapped values in mm
mm_values = []

# Define a function to read the analog value and convert it to mm
def read_analog_to_mm():
    analog_value = adc.read_adc(3, gain=GAIN)
    mm_value = np.interp(analog_value, analog_values, mapping_equation)
    return int(mm_value)

# Define a function to step the motor
def step_motor():
    GPIO.output(PUL_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    GPIO.output(PUL_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(DELAY)

# Use multithreading to read the analog value and step the motor simultaneously
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future_mm_values = {executor.submit(read_analog_to_mm) for i in range(STEPS)}
    future_motor_steps = {executor.submit(step_motor) for i in range(STEPS)}

    # Collect the mapped mm values
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_mm_values):
        mm_values.append(future.result())

# Set up the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(mm_values, range(len(mm_values)))

# Invert the y-axis so that the greatest value starts from the origin
ax.invert_yaxis()

# Format the y-axis to show only integer values
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(integer=True))

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# Cleanup the GPIO pins
GPIO.cleanup(
```

Why when I run this last code I get no sign of life whatsoever?

Comment: If you ran that code you would get an error message.  It is incomplete.  Please edit your question and include the complete code AND indicate what happens when you run the program.

Comment: Try writing in paragraphs

Comment: hi there; sorry did not notice that, my bad:  here the whole code :

Comment: # Define a function to read the analog value and convert it to mm
def read_analog_to_mm():
    analog_value = adc.read_adc(3, gain=GAIN)
    mm_value = np.interp(analog_value, analog_values, mapping_equation)
    return int(mm_value)

Comment: # Define a function to step the motor
def step_motor():
    GPIO.output(PUL_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    GPIO.output(PUL_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(DELAY)

Comment: # Use multithreading to read the analog value and step the motor simultaneously
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future_mm_values = {executor.submit(read_analog_to_mm) for i in range(STEPS)}
    future_motor_steps = {executor.submit(step_motor) for i in range(STEPS)}

    # Collect the mapped mm values
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_mm_values):
        mm_values.append(future.result())

Comment: # Set up the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(mm_values, range(len(mm_values)))

# Invert the y-axis so that the greatest value starts from the origin
ax.invert_yaxis()

# Format the y-axis to show only integer values
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(integer=True))

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# Cleanup the GPIO pins
GPIO.cleanup()

Comment: .....sorry but I had to split the code in multiple comments cz too many characters:  As I mentioned when I try to run it I do not get any kind of error, I only hear the stepper motor that is active(the ENABLE pin on the driver is ON by deafult and  I do not use it in the code so as soon as there is power the stepper is activated)...on the terminal I don't get any error whatsoever, it just appear a regular terminal when any other python code is running...i try to attach a screenshot

Comment: why don't you edit your question and add the code there? ... nobody will look at the code in comments ... also delete the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import concurrent.futures

# Set the GPIO mode to BCM
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Define the PUL and DIR pins
PUL_PIN = 18
DIR_PIN = 23

# Set the PUL and DIR pins as output
GPIO.setup(PUL_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(DIR_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

# Define the step delay
DELAY = 0.0001

# Define the number of steps
STEPS = 127000

# Set the direction to clockwise
GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)

# Create an ADS1115 ADC instance
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

# Set the gain (the range of the analog input voltage)
GAIN = 2/3

# Set the mapping equation to convert analog values to mm
analog_values = [4800, 13600]
mm_range = [50, 300]
mapping_equation = np.interp(analog_values, [min(analog_values), 
max(analog_values)], mm_range)

# Create a list to store the mapped values in mm
mm_values = []

# Define a function to read the analog value and convert it to mm
def read_analog_to_mm():
    analog_value = adc.read_adc(3, gain=GAIN)
    mm_value = np.interp(analog_value, analog_values, mapping_equation)
    return int(mm_value)

# Define a function to step the motor
def step_motor():
   GPIO.output(PUL_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
   time.sleep(DELAY)
   GPIO.output(PUL_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(DELAY)

# Use multithreading to read the analog value and step the motor simultaneously
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
   future_mm_values = {executor.submit(read_analog_to_mm) for i in range(STEPS)}
   future_motor_steps = {executor.submit(step_motor) for i in range(STEPS)}

# Collect the mapped mm values
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_mm_values):
    mm_values.append(future.result())

# Set up the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(mm_values, range(len(mm_values)))

# Invert the y-axis so that the greatest value starts from the origin
ax.invert_yaxis()

# Format the y-axis to show only integer values
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(integer=True))

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# Cleanup the GPIO pins
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?